# SQL update table - value from previous row with a value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that looks like this:

[image]

and I want my result to look likes this:

[image]

So if the value is 1 it should be replaced by next value that is not 1 looking upward on the num column.

I tried `update table` with `LAG` and internal selects and CTE and search for hours but couldn't find a solution.

I hope someone has a hint how I can do that.

PS: I don't know a better way to integrate my table than using a picture. Can I find somewhere ainstruction how to use this "mark down" to improve my question?

And I also had the wrong tag here. But all other stuff I used did not work

Comment: You mention `LAG` and `CTE` but you tagged this as MySQL which doesn't have those, what database are you using?

Comment: It is preferable to use mark-down to show a table rather than images.  Also, your images are not appearing in your question.

Comment: I edited my question. @BPS how do I use "mark down"? ollie it is a microsoft sql. I changed the tags now. If you have any suggestens on tags i can use here i would be thankfull too :)

Comment: Why were you not successful with `LAG`?   What did you try and what error did you get?

Answer (score 0):

This answer relates to MySQL, because the OP originally indicated as such...

Take note of both the content of answer, and the way in which the answer is formatted.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(level VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
,num INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,value VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
('root',110,'AAA'),
('root',109,'1'),
('root',108,'1'),
('root',107,'BBB'),
('root',106,'1'),
('root',105,'ccc'),
('root',104,'1'),
('root',103,'DDD'),
('root',102,'1'),
('root',101,'1'),
('root',100,'EEE'),
('root', 99,'1'),
('root', 98,'1');

SELECT level
     , num
     , x value 
  FROM 
     ( SELECT a.*
            , CASE WHEN value = 1 THEN @prev ELSE value END x
            , CASE WHEN value <> 1 THEN @prev := value END y 
         FROM my_table a 
            , (SELECT @prev := null) vars 
        ORDER 
           BY num DESC
     ) n
 ORDER 
    BY num DESC;
+-------+-----+-------+
| level | num | value |
+-------+-----+-------+
| root  | 110 | AAA   |
| root  | 109 | AAA   |
| root  | 108 | AAA   |
| root  | 107 | BBB   |
| root  | 106 | BBB   |
| root  | 105 | ccc   |
| root  | 104 | ccc   |
| root  | 103 | DDD   |
| root  | 102 | DDD   |
| root  | 101 | DDD   |
| root  | 100 | EEE   |
| root  |  99 | EEE   |
| root  |  98 | EEE   |
+-------+-----+-------+
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailes information! So I will just enter all my Code as a Code next time :) Instead of copying and using it I would like to understand some of the code. 1. What is the x or y after the END for?  2. What is the "n" after the ) for? 3. What does the (SELECT @prev := null) vars do? and 4. Would suggest to create a CTE with outut and use this one and a join within the UPDATE?

Comment: @StefanHubaer They're all aliases. You originally tagged your question MySQL, which doesn't support CTE, so this is a way of emulating that kind of behaviour, by constructing a variable. In MySQL, variables need to be initialised before use. This can be done with a separate query [`SET @var = null;`] or within the query itself, as above.